# C# Game Programming: Is it better to save or calculate non-changing datum?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm programming a game in the C# XNA framework and something has been bugging me for quite some time.  I'm never certain whether it's to the advantage of a program to save data (that is to say, store it within a local variable) or to calculate it each frame.

While I've decided that it's better to continuously calculate data that changes each frame (such as the position of the player, the positions of automated sprites, et cetera), I'm uncertain whether or not I should save a piece of data like the width of a window or calculate it each frame.  My fear is that calculating a piece of data, regardless of how small it may be, sixty times every second will generate quite a bit of overhead, so thus far I've been sticking to saving a lot of material.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to get across:

```
//  Scenario 1: Save the data

//  This class represents an entry within a menu.
public class MenuEntry
{
    //  The constructor takes a SpriteFont variable to calculate the size of 
    //  the given string (which is the text used to represent this entry in a 
    //  menu) and save that data for later access
    public MenuEntry(string entryText, SpriteFont font)
    {
        this.entryText = entryText;

        //  Initializes a local value of the font to lessen the burden of method calls.
        SpriteFont font = menuScreen.GameInstance.MenuFont;

        //  Initialize the bounding rectangle for this 'MenuEntry' object.
        entryRectangle = new Rectangle();

        //  Based on the text given, adjust the values of the rectangle.
        entryRectangle.Height = font.LineSpacing;
        entryRectangle.Width = (int)font.MeasureString(entryText).X;
    }

    //  Object methods

    //  This method simply sets the location of the 'hitbox' of this MenuEntry based
    //  on the given position.
    public void SetLocation(int x, int y)
    {
        entryRectangle.X = x;
        entryRectangle.Y = y;
    }

    //  Object fields

    //  Rectangle that represents the 'hitbox' for this MenuEntry.  In other
    //  words, the place on the screen over which the mouse can hover to cause
    //  this MenuEntry to be the selected item on the menu
    private Rectangle entryRectangle;

    //  The 'entryText' is the string representation of this MenuEntry object in
    //  a menu.
    private string entryText;
}

//  Scenario 2: Calculate per frame

//  This class also represents an entry within a menu.
public class MenuEntry
{
    //  The constructor simply initializes the value of the text field
    public MenuEntry(string entryText)
    {
        this.entryText = entryText;
    }

    //  Object methods

    //  Instead of saving the data, these methods allow this MenuEntry
    //  to calculate its 'hitbox' whenever this method is called, 
    //  returning the width and height variables associated with the
    //  text representation of this MenuEntry object.
    public virtual int GetWidth(SpriteFont font)
    {
        return (int)font.MeasureString(Text).X;
    }

    public virtual int GetHeight(SpriteFont font)
    {
        return font.LineSpacing;
    }

    //  Object fields

    //  The MenuEntry still must know where it's located, but this component
    //  is less memory intensive than a 'Rectangle' object (correct me if
    //  I'm wrong on this one)
    private Vector2 position;

    //  This property allows for the controlling menu to place and replace the
    //  MenuEntry, though this value must be calculated each frame even though
    //  the position may be the same for each frame.
    public Vector2 Position
    {
        get { return position; }
        set { position = value; }
    }

    //  The 'entryText' is the string representation of this MenuEntry object in
    //  a menu.
    private string entryText;
}

//  Example in menu:

public class Menu
{
    //  For the sake of simplicity, the constructor simply receives a list of entries
    //  and initializes them to a local variable.  If we're using Scenario 1, the  
    //  positions for each rectangle must be set.
    public class Menu(SpriteFont menuFont, List<MenuEntry> menuEntries)
    {
        this.menuFont = menuFont;
        this.menuEntries = menuEntries;

        #if Scenario 1

        Vector2 position = new Vector2(0f, 175f);

        for(int i = 0; i < menuEntries.Count; i++)
        {
            //  Initialize a local reference to the current MenuEntry.
            MenuEntry menuEntry = menuEntries[i];

            //  Adjust this entry toward the center of the screen.  Assume it
            //  has access to a static viewport variable.
            position.X = Game.Viewport.Width / 2 - menuEntry.GetWidth(this) / 2;

            //  Set the entry's position to the calculated position.  There must be
            //  casts as these are floating-point values.
            menuEntry.SetLocation((int)position.X, (int)position.Y);

            //  Move down for the next entry the size of this entry
            position.Y += menuEntry.GetHeight(this);
        }

        #endif
    }

    //  This method is called by the main update method once per frame.
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        #if Scenario 1

        //  Nothing, as the MenuEntry items don't need to move and their positions
        //  have already been set.

        #elif Scenario 2

        Vector2 position = new Vector2(0f, 175f);

        for(int i = 0; i < menuEntries.Count; i++)
        {
            //  Initialize a local reference to the current MenuEntry.
            MenuEntry menuEntry = menuEntries[i];

            //  Adjust this entry toward the center of the screen.  Assume it
            //  has access to a static viewport variable.
            position.X = Game.Viewport.Width / 2 - menuEntry.GetWidth(this) / 2;

            //  Set the entry's position
            menuEntry.Position = position;

            //  Move down for the next entry the size of this entry
            position.Y += menuEntry.GetHeight(this);
        }

        #endif
    }

    //  Object fields

    //  The list of MenuEntry items associated with this Menu.
    private List<MenuEntry> menuEntries;

    //  The font used for this Menu.
    private SpriteFont menuFont;
}
```

Though the example is a bit long, I feel as though it adequately encapsulates my question.  So, is it better to save more data to an object (in the case of the example, save a rectangle structure) or is it better to calculate this data each frame?  Note that the data I'm speaking of doesn't change between frames.

Comment: It depends on the exact situation in your code. Try profiling.

Comment: How would you recommend I profile in a situation like this?  Just run a series of calculations for each scenario and export that data in a formatted form to a .txt file?

Comment: You don't need each scenario at first. The first thing you do with a profiler is finding the bottleneck. Typically in unoptimized code a few short pieces of code take >90% of the time.

Comment: Why even update the size every frame? You could hook the `Window.ClientSizeChanged` event ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamewindow.clientsizechanged.aspx)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

60 times per second in *nothing* for simple calculations. Your computer can do several million simple calculations per second.

Chose the one that produces the easier to maintain code. And since windows can be resized I strongly recommend recalculating window based stuff like aspect ratio, projection matrix etc on each frame.

Such performance concerns are only relevant for code that gets executed very often. Say >1 million times a second.

For rare execution only expensive calls such as IO matter.

So I'm with svick on this issue: Profile to find the bottleneck and then optimize it. For all other code use the clearest simplest version.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this correctly, you're saying that I should calculate the position each second since these calculations won't generate much overhead?  As you've said, that would make window size recalculations MUCH simpler than they are now...

Comment: Another +1. Optimise only that code which is known to be slow - and this knowledge should only be acquired by profiling.

Answer (score 2):

More memory usage or slower performance. That's what it boils down to. Which is more critical in your case?

Comment: In this case: Probably neither. And time memory trade-offs are often not so simple due to CPU caches.

Comment: If neither is important in the OP's case, then it's more of a "good practice" question. And to be honest, if performance doesn't matter so much, I would go with the recalculations. I generally dislike the idea of using memory you don't need.

Comment: It definitely is a 'best practice' question.  I'm just looking for whichever is best in the long run, and I didn't know that per frame calculations, given that they're simple calculations, generate negligible overhead.  That being said, the general consensus seems to be that per frame calculations are recommended over saving information.

Answer (score 2):

**Do whatever makes for the easiest to read and understand code.** You should only start worrying about optimisation if you have an *actual* performance problem.

Code to handle things like menu layout is *never* going to require optimisation - certainly at the level of micro-optimisations like: how big certain data types are, the overhead of method calls, and whether you need to cache results.

Start worrying about that when you're making a 100+ object physics simulation. Or a 10000+ object particle system. Or a 100+ polygon collision-detection routine.

Puting this kind of effort into a 10+ entry menu is *insane*, and that makes it difficult to give any actual performance advice.

**In many cases caching data can actually reduce performance**, because the CPU can do some fairly complicated calculations in the time it takes to read and write data from memory. The heaviest thing in your code is `SpriteFont.MeasureString` - and even that is probably "fast enough" in your situation.

Mentioning memory access patterns is also worthwhile - in cases where you don't have a large number of data items, the size of each individual item doesn't matter much (eg: `Rectangle` vs `Vector2`, strings) because memory is fetched into the CPU cache in much larger blocks than that.

**I can't stress enough how bad of an idea it is to be optimising this at all!** Just write nice, easy-to-read code.

Personally I'd be focusing more on using the CLR Profiler to ensure you're not allocating memory during your draw-update cycle (causing the garbage collector to run intermittently), rather than worrying about low-level CPU and memory-access-time stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have much choice, every frame you should update all of your moving objects.